# Use javascript dynamic methods on this

Tags: javascript, class, object, dynamic, this

I was writting objects on JavaScript in object notation, and calling methods dynamically like this:

```
var myObj = {
    method1: function(params){
        /* decide what other method to call based on an ajax call */
        myObj[ajaxCallResult](ajaxCallParams);
    },

    method2: function(params){
        /* do whatever */
    },

    method3: function(params){
        /* do another thing */
    }
}
```

Now I need to rewritte the entire thing in class notation, but I'm having some troubles at this point as I need to call methods dynamically over "this", but I'm getting the error "TypeError: this[myMethod] is not a function.". Obviously there's a function written with that name so I think I can use that way to call methonds when using "this". This is the way I'm using now:

```
class myObj2 extends myObj1 {
    constructor(){
        super();
        /* do whatever */
    }
    method1(params){
        /* decide what other method to call based on an ajax call */
        this[ajaxCallResult](ajaxCallParams);
    }
    method2(params){
        /* do stuff 1 */
    }
    method3(params){
        /* do stuff 2 */
    }
}
```

But this one is definitely not working. Is there a correct way to do what I need in this case?

**EDIT 1**

As @sabithpocker sugested, here's the ajax code (using jQuery), and yes, the call is in the ajax callback

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: url, // from another var
    data: data, // created from the params gotten plus a few extras
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(r){
    console.log('r.method -> '+r.method); // definitelly getting what i want
    /* Here I tried a few ways: */
    this[r.method](r.params); // "TypeError: this.[r.method] is not a function
    this.r.method(r.params); // "TypeError: this.r.method is not a function

    /* also I assigned this to self in the class constructor (thanks to @Patrick Evans' comment, I consoled log this and it was the $.ajax() object) */
    self[r.method](r.params); // same error
    self.r.method(r.params); // same error
    // surprisingly not getting a "self is not defined" error
});
```

**EDIT 2** (Solved)

As Khauri McClain said, the way was to assign this to a var before the ajax call instead of in the constructor. This is the result:

```
class myObj{
    method1(){
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            // conf
        }).done(function(r){
            self[r.method](r.params);
        });
    }
    method2(params){}
    method3(params){}
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `method1`? If you don't call it properly `this` may not be what you think it is. Have you verified, using console.log or debugger that `ajaxCallResult` actually holds a proper string matching the method name?

Comment: _this one is definitely not working_ -- what is the problem that you're facing? Is there any error?

Comment: "*Now I need to rewritte the entire thing in class notation*" - Why?

Comment: `this[ajaxCallResult](ajaxCallParams);` are you calling this line inside an AJAX callback function? `this` can be different if called from a different call-site, can you add a minimum code of the AJAX call as well?

Comment: @31piy the error is written in there: "TypeError: this[myMethod] is not defined.

Comment: @Bergi I was told to

Comment: So the ajax callback is inside of `method1` correct? Instead of assigning self in the class constructor, try assigning `var self = this` right before the ajax call. Try doing `console.log(this, self)` to make sure `this` and `self` are what you think it is (odds are it isn't)

Answer (score -1):

change your answer from this[mymethod] to this.mymethod()

Comment: In OP's case i think `ajaxCallResult` is a string, so using `[]` is correct.